# Why is this mysql syntax wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I am executing the follow mysql query and getting error saying wrong syntax.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PS.INFO WHERE IPADDRESS='1.1.1.1' AND ID='YYY' AND (TYPE='PAID' 0R  TYPE='FREE') AND EXPIRYTIME IS NULL;
```

Please help me out with the correct syntax?

Comment: Next time, please include at least the error message you got. It makes it easier for everyone to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your wrote `0R` (zero-R) instead of `OR` (O-R).

Answer (score 5):

TYPE='PAID' 0R  TYPE='FREE'

```
OR
```

appears to have a zero instead of an O

Answer (score 4):

The error always tells you where to look. In this case it says "near '0R..."

And sure enough, that's a zero, not an `O`. It should be the word `OR`.